# list of None's is returned after list comprehension - python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

here all_sentences_2d is a list of lists, contains the list of sentences in each tweet:

```
all_sentences_2d = [['tweet_1_sentence_1', 'tweet_1_sentence_2'],['tweet_2_sentence_1', 'tweet_2_sentence_2']]
```

I want to append an empty sentence after the sentences of each tweet.
I mean I want all_sentences_2d to be like that:

```
all_sentences_2d = [['tweet_1_sentence_1', 'tweet_1_sentence_2', ''],['tweet_2_sentence_1', 'tweet_2_sentence_2', '']]
```

I used this list comprehension to do that:

```
all_sentences_2d = [tweet_sentences.append('') for tweet_sentences in all_sentences_2d]
```

but I got that:

```
all_sentences_2d = [None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

While debugging, I've seen the appending operation done correctly in the all elements but after that becomes all None. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) updates the list in place and returns `None`. You can try this, though:

```
[tweet_sentences + [''] for tweet_sentences in all_sentences_2d]
```

Although I would prefer a plain `for`-loop here:

```
for v in all_sentences_2d:
    v.append('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> all_sentences_2d = [['tweet_1_sentence_1', 'tweet_1_sentence_2'],['tweet_2_sentence_1', 'tweet_2_sentence_2']]
>>> map(lambda l: l+[' '], all_sentences_2d )
[['tweet_1_sentence_1', 'tweet_1_sentence_2', ' '], ['tweet_2_sentence_1', 'tweet_2_sentence_2', ' ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done but you need to be careful of your syntax, you have your `if` statement in the wrong place for a start. Look at the example below, note that the list comprehension is NOT assigned to a variabe.

```
words        = ['1', '12', '123', '1234']
shortest     = []
longest      = []
shortest_len = 3
[shortest.append(i) if len(i) <= shortest_len else longest.append(i) for i in words]
```